# Single word for "more than once"

Tags: single-word-requests, translation

Is there a single word to describe the occurrence of a pattern more than once?

> This word exists in a file **more than once**.

According to an online Czech–* dictionary, these would be the equivalents in other languages:

- *mehrmals* in German
- *многократно* in Russian
- *aliquotiens* in Latin
- *kilkakrotnie* in Polish
- *několikrát* or *víckrát* in Czech

Comment: If the translations you gave are correct, why didn't you check the English translation? All of the words above mean the same thing, with no subtle differences that I could tell. Is there something about an English translation that you didn't feel was right?

Comment: Checking the English translation was the first thing I did of course, however in the dictionaries that were available to me, translations were not as terse as I needed them to be: "more than once", "multiple times", "a few times", "several times". I believe that is the purpose of questions tagged with "single-word-requests" category.

Comment: Try google translate. It gives one word translations that are often a good start. In this case it was spot on for each word in each language that you gave.

Comment: I did that as well. "more times", "several times", "multiple times". Do you see any single word? :)

Comment: Bear in mind that, in English, *repeatedly* is subtly different from *more than once*. *Twice* is not repeatedly to most ears, for example. Bit *twice* is more than once.

Comment: Yes, google translate gave the single words already given in the answers. Google has regional servers that can give different results. Maybe this applies to translation results, too. I used your non-English words as inputs, by the way.

Comment: True, that I was google translating just the Czech version of the word "víckrát" (as it is my native language), which did not offer any single word solution. 

Also true about the subtle differences between "repeatedly" and "more than once", but to my case (see my comment to Manish Girl's answer) it absolutely suits.

Comment: also recurs or repeats line_exists/line_repeats

Comment: @SrJoven: That sounds good as well! Although I like the implied inheritance (part of functionality from `line_exists` shared by `line_exists_repeatedly`) which is the case here.

Comment: Caution: Do not take chances. *More than once* is exactly that -- no other single word may give the same meaning.

Comment: @Kris: It feels to me, that the meaning of the expressions is close enough. In my case, it also improves the readability and expresivness of my code greatly I think.

Comment: also line_exists_again ... Because of course it does. :)

Comment: @CanisLupus Speak for yourself; 'twice' classifies as 'repeatedly' to me. Though 'repeatedly' does not always classify as 'twice'.

Comment: Watch your capitalization: *german* is an elaborate round dance, *polish* is something you apply to nails, shoes, or cars, and *english* is the spin you put on a ball in billiards. Languages are *always* capitalized.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I would go with repeatedly.

> The word exists in a file repeatedly.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: +1 Though twice is not repeatedly. There's much difference.

Comment: To repeat means to do something more than once, so I'm under the impression repeatedly would be applicable for more than once also.

Comment: @Kris +1. Repeatedly definitely _does not_ indicate **twice**.

Comment: I think it's still technically legal to use "multiply," pronouncing the 'y' same as in "repeatedly."  Or you could go with the ugly "nonuniquely."   aaack, should have reloaded to see this was already provided in an answer.

Comment: "repeatedly" feels to my non-native self more like "many times in close proximity" than "more than once"... But I can't think of a better alternative, I admit.

Comment: @Kris and ManishGiri wrong, wrong, wrong. Repeatedly is technically accurate to describe twice.

Comment: @TylerH please provide a reference to a definition that allows for twice to be included in repeatedly.

Comment: @GreenAsJade Simply type it into Google and you will be provided with a valid definition.

Comment: @TylerH http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/repeatedly  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repeatedly  http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/repeatedly  http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/repeatedly **See also:** https://www.google.com/webhp?tab=ww&ei=7qYGVIHWJdHh8AXR6oCgAg&ved=0CBkQ1S4#q=%22repeatedly%22&tbm=nws

Comment: @TylerH Hope that helps.

Comment: Of course I googled it first.  Each definition I found has variants of "over and over again".   This is more than twice...

Comment: @Kris all of those give the exact same definition, which, in usage today, is used to mean two or more times.

Answer (score 12):

Think about where you want to use the expression. If the context is somewhat technical, you can use:

> There are multiple occurrences of this word in the file.

If not, there are several other words/expressions you could use:

> - frequently
> - often
> - regularly
> - a number of times
> - recurrently

Comment: I needed to name 2 oposing functions, so I was looking for something as terse as possible. Like `line_exists` vs `line_exists_repeatedly` - so yes, repeatedly from Aelexe's answer does the job!

Comment: I think `recurrently` is better fitting that `repeatedly`.

Comment: Since you want to make two opposing functions you might want to call the first one `line_exists_once` since you want to check whether it exists once but not twice or multiple times/repeatedly.

Comment: ```repeatedly``` is the idiomatic choice. There are multiple ```recurrences``` of the word, using a word such as recurrently is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

In Patent law, you would say a plurality when meaning more than one. This is used instead of "several", "multiple" and removes ambiguity in the document.

Comment: Patent law is not a good guide to English usage.  For example you cannot make multiple claims in a single statement, discouraging the use of *or* such as in phases like "It uses fluorine, chlorine or bromine".  The patent lawyers then rewrite this as "It uses one of fluorine, chlorine and bromine" thereby undermining both the legal rule on multiple claims and the standard use of English.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the problem that "repeatedly" does not cover "twice", you could use "multiply", which is the adverb form of "multiple".  It has been in use since 1881, according to [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/multiply) (definition 2):

> " in a multiple manner"

There is a downside, of course, that it is is spelt the same as the verb "multiply", although it is pronounced differently.  Hence, your example would be

> **line_exists** and **line_exists_multiply**

Comment: In the case where the word was used twice it is likely one would simply say ```'twice'```. ```Multiply``` suffers the same awkwardness as ```recurrently```.

Answer (score 0):

Since the question asks for a word defining the condition "more than once", perhaps "non-uniquely" would fit the bill.

"This word exists in a file non-uniquely."

Answer (score 0):

Consider switching the syntax to "This word reoccurs."  "This word reappears" also seems better for as few as 2 appearances.

I read that recur means at regular intervals, whereas reoccur does not require regular intervals (see http://grammarist.com/usage/recur-reoccur/).  So, reoccur is better than recur for your purpose here.